# BASH - Simply to remove spaces before the first character and the last character

Tags: bash

Simply to remove spaces before the first character and the last character

```
FOO="   ffs ff ssdf hfdh     hfghfghfgh hhgfg      "

result
ffs ff ssdf hfdh     hfghfghfgh hhgfg
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the goal is to modify the variable (in order of decreasing portability):

```
# POSIX
foo=${foo#"${foo%%[! ]*}"} foo=${foo%"${foo##*[! ]}"}

# Bash/ksh
${BASH_VERSION+'false'} || shopt -s extglob
foo=${foo##+( )} foo=${foo%%+( )}

# Bash4/ksh
IFS=' ' read -rd '' foo < <(printf %s "$foo")

# Bash4/ksh93
${KSH_VERSION+'false'} || typeset -n BASH_REMATCH=.sh.match
[[ $foo =~ ^\ *([! ].*[! ])\ *$ ]]
foo=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# ksh93
foo=${foo/~(K)*(\ )@([! ]*[! ])*(\ )/\2}
```

As usual it's impossible to recommend a best approach without knowing both what you're starting with and what you want to do with the result.

Comment: The only true (in terms of shell coding) answer. Keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "   ffs ff ssdf hfdh     hfghfghfgh hhgfg      " | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash v4, then this should work for you.

```
FOO=${FOO:1:-1}
```

Comment: That's a substring expansion. It will just strip one character off the ends -- not the desired effect. If you require Bash 3 then use `$#-1` instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

echo $FOO | sed 's/^ *//' | sed 's/ *$//'